# Does clusterApply in R affect calculation of average for each layer of raster brick?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

I have raster bricks for daily minimum and maximum temperatures from [Daymet](https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1840). The geographic extent is continental U.S. Each brick has 365 layers, one for each day of the year. I want to calculate the mean daily temperature from pair of min. and max. bricks by year. It seems the `overlay()` function in the `R` `raster` package does what I want. For example:

```
library(raster)
tmin <- brick("tmin_2018.nc")
tmax <- brick("tmax_2018.nc")
tmean <- overlay(tmin, tmax, fun=mean)
```

The thing is, it takes a long time and a lot of RAM. More RAM than I have. I have access to high performance computing cluster. I have code for this process on the cluster that utilizes the OpenMPI utility and can provide parallel processing. My test case only uses 5 layers. I request 6 nodes from the cluster for the job.

```
library(iterators)
library(foreach)
library(snow)
library(parallel)
library(Rmpi)
library(compiler)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)
print(mpi.universe.size())

nras <- brick("infil/ras_in/daymet_v3_tmax_2009_na.nc4")
xras <- brick("infil/ras_in/daymet_v3_tmin_2009_na.nc4")

cl <- makeCluster( mpi.universe.size() - 1, type='MPI' )

clusterExport(cl, "nras")
clusterExport(cl, "xras")
clusterExport(cl, c('overlay', 'writeRaster', 'brick'))

easy_fn <- function(i) {
        overlay(nras[[i]], xras[[i]], fun = mean)
        }

out <- clusterApply(cl, 1:5, fun=easy_fn)
outbrickb <- brick(out)
writeRaster(outbrickb, "outfil/rasout/testbrick.tif", wopt=list(datatype="FLT4S", filetype="GTiff"), overwrite=T)
```

And that also works. But the values are different. When I calculate the mean for one layer (day), with the first code chunk above I get values between -55.255 and 31.08. After running small number of layers as a test on HPC cluster with the 2nd code chunk I get values between -50 and 44.5. If things were off by decimal places, I wouldn't be concerned, but the values are far different. Is there something I'm missing in how `clusterApply()` or my little `easy_fn()` work vs. just calling `overlay()` that will lead to different values?

Comment: My $0.02: (i) Unless there is random number generation involved, you should expect to get identical results from a parallel framework.  (ii) Before bringing in the parallelization machinery, make sure you can achieve what you want using one of the basic apply functions, e.g. `lapply()`.  Only when that works, try to parallelize, e.g. replacing `lapply()` with `parLapply()`.  BTW, did you mean to use `parallel::clusterApply()`, which I think is a bit more low-level that, say, `parLapply()`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to attach all those packages. It looks like you're only using **parallel**, **Rmpi**, and **raster**. Better to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easiest and faster to use `terra` instead of `raster`

Example data

```
library(terra)
tmin <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) / 10
tmax <- tmin + 10
```

Solution

```
tavg1 <- mean(tmin, tmax)
```

Note that this works in `terra` because it computes the parallel mean (by layer), whereas `raster` would return the mean of all layers. To get that with `terra` you would do

```
m <- mean(c(tmin, tmax))
```

The equivalent to `overlay` in `raster` is `terra::lapp`, and one might need it for more complex cases.

```
tavg2 <- lapp(sds(tmin, tmax), function(x,y) (x + y)/2)

all(values(tavg1) == values(tavg2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Now with `raster`

Example data

```
library(raster)
tmin <- brick(tmin)
tmax <- brick(tmax)
```

Using an algebraic approach could be faster than `overlay`

```
tavg3 <- (tmin + tmax) / 2
tavg4 <- overlay(tmin, tmax, fun = mean)
```

With your function

```
easy_fn <- function(i) {
    overlay(tmin[[i]], tmax[[i]], fun = mean)
}

x <- lapply(1:nlayers(tmin), easy_fn)
tavg5 <- stack(x)
```

And now in parallel

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
clusterExport(cl, c('overlay', 'tmin', 'tmax'))
out <- clusterApply(cl, 1:nlayers(tmin), fun=easy_fn)
stopCluster(cl)
tavg6 <- stack(out)

all(values(tavg1) == values(tavg3))
#[1] TRUE
all(values(tavg1) == values(tavg4))
#[1] TRUE
all(values(tavg1) == values(tavg5))
#[1] TRUE
all(values(tavg1) == values(tavg6))
#[1] TRUE
```

All results are the same.

Now with your larger datasets, and timing the different approaches

```
fmx <- "daymet_v4_daily_hi_tmax_2015.nc"
fmn <- "daymet_v4_daily_hi_tmin_2015.nc"
library(terra)
tmin <- rast(fmn)
tmax <- rast(fmx)
system.time(tavg1 <- mean(tmin, tmax))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.88    0.75    2.62 

system.time(tavg2 <- lapp(sds(tmin, tmax), function(x,y) (x + y)/2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.34    1.40    3.76
```

These are clearly the fastest approaches (see below). You can add a filename argument to `lapp`, but with `mean` you would have to also use `writeRaster`

And with `raster`

```
library(raster)
tmin <- brick(fmn)
tmax <- brick(fmx)
system.time(tavg3 <- (tmin + tmax) / 2)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  13.94    4.42   18.47
```

In this case `overlay` is extraordinarily slow

```
system.time(tavg4 <- overlay(tmin, tmax, fun = mean))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 478.06    5.78  488.16 

system.time(x <- lapply(1:nlayers(tmin), easy_fn))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 474.03    5.14  482.42 
tavg5 <- stack(x)
```

It does go faster with parallelization; but not enough to make it worth pursuing

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
clusterExport(cl, c('overlay', 'tmin', 'tmax'))
system.time(out <- clusterApply(cl, 1:nlayers(tmin), fun=easy_fn))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.53    0.78  184.82 
stopCluster(cl)
tavg6 <- stack(out)
```

I do not see a meaningful difference between the sequential and parallelized approaches

```
d <- tavg6 - tavg4
d
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 584, 284, 165856, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
#extent     : -5802750, -5518750, -622500, -38500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=lcc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : r_tmp_2021-11-20_103534_54328_41274.grd 
#names      :       layer.1,       layer.2,       layer.3,       layer.4,       layer.5,       layer.6,       layer.7,       layer.8,       layer.9,      layer.10,      layer.11,      layer.12,      layer.13,      layer.14,      layer.15, ... 
#min values : -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, -9.536743e-07, ... 
#max values :  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07,  9.536743e-07, ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer.